# How to get changed dropdown value in PHP page when I will select dropdown in same page

Tags: php, jquery

This is my code and page name is `xyz.php`

```
<select name="limit" id="limit" onchange="displayVals()">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>      
</select>

<?php
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    echo $limit;
?>

<script>
function displayVals() {
  var singleValues = $("#limit").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xyz.php",
    data: {account: singleValues},
    async: false,
  });
}
</script>
```

Basically I need when I select drop dropdown then I will see result of dropdown value

For example , if I select 10 then it will be print $limit variable in same time. which will see 10.

Please any suggestion

Comment: You can't do that.. php's run's on server whereas JS run's on browser

Comment: How can i do in same time?

Comment: you can send selected value back to the server using ajax

Comment: BTW .. what is the need of the Value `$limit`

Comment: Basically i want to change pagination per page limit if i select 10 then 10 row is show and if i select 25 then it is show 25 row in page?

Comment: You should use JS to print the value of the selected option.

Comment: php will be executed first in the server. when you set the $limit, it doesn't know the value of the select, because this is rendered later on the browser. you can get the value of select like you do already and use it accordingly
    
    function displayVals() {

    var singleValues = $("#limit").val();

Comment: Thanks a lot all , i have get own solution

Answer (score 0):

I have get a great idea and i am successful

here will be change php and java script little which is below

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['limit']))
{
   $limit = $_GET['limit'];
   echo $limit;
}
?>

<script>
function displayVals() {
    var singleValues = $("#limit").val();
    window.location ="xyz.php?limit="+singleValues;
}
</script>
```